# Using .Net NamedPipes in a VB6 to communicate with C# application

Tags: c#, vb6, named-pipes

**UPDATE:**
1 - New C# application exposes NamedPipeServerStream(System.IO.Pipes) on .Net framework.
2 - Legacy VB6 needs to communicate with the C# NamedPipeServerStream.
3 - Until now VB6 resides in a system without .Net framework. But, going forward both C# and legacy application will be on a computer which has .Net installed.
3 - Can VB6 talk to the C# pipe server using **CallNamedPipe()** and is this approach hassle free in maintenance of the communication betwen the applications?

Any resources I can look into or other approaches ?

**Old question:**
I have a legacy VB 6.0 application which needs to communicate with a newer C# application using .Net NamedPipes.

Currently, the legacy VB6 application sits on a system without .Net.
When I install .Net framework and the C# NamedPipeServer application on that system, how can the legacy VB6 program communicate with the C# application over NamedPipes ?

Please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with a VB6 application which needed data from a set of WCF services.

The easiest way to achieve this is to put the logic to communicate with remote systems in a .Net assembly which exposes operations via COM and call that assembly from your VB6 code.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute(v=vs.100).aspx as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using System.IO.Pipes for this then thankfully you don't have to deal with the cruft and interoperabiity nightmare known as WCF.

To write a nice pipe client in VB6 requires a control or class written in C++ in order to manage the async I/O and raise events.  Otherwise you will probably have to use a Timer to poll for input, but it is all fairly straightforward API I/O then.

I don't know of any cheap or free ActiveX DLL or OCX generally available today, and I doubt Microsoft ever produced one.  But the Timer-driven polling approach should have plenty of examples out there to get you started.  And it spares you the terrible inefficiency, stops and sputters, and giant memory footprint of saddling your VB6 program with all the overhead of using .Net Interop.

But that is always an option.